# My App uses only Storage Permission, does it need privacy policy?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, privacy-policy

Surprisingly no precise explanation on the internet!

My App is a simple browser, it uses Storage Permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

only for download files & import/export own bookmarks (not other browser's). This app doesn't use location permission!

1) Android documentation tells Storage permission is sensitive, so does this app needs privacy policy?

2) Android documentation tells storing & transmitting personal data need privacy policy, but how about this situation? Because this app doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app can read user photos from SD card / shared storage, so yes, it needs a privacy policy.

Google has been requiring privacy policy from any app on Play Store for a while, regardless of the permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much, got the point,One question, should the privacy policy be GDPR, CalOPPA compliant? (for the above permissions)

Comment: I confirm pelya's answer, Google is actually [quite clear on this](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/#sensitive). Regarding your question in the comment, this depends on who your app is targeting. Though GDPR practices are definitely encouraged, since that makes you pretty much ready for the rest of the world.

Answer (score 2):

All Google Play's policies are documented at the [Google Play Policy center](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/).

In this case [it says](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/):

"If your app handles personal or sensitive user data (including personally identifiable information, financial and payment information, authentication information, phonebook or contact data, microphone and camera sensor data, and sensitive device data) then your app must:

- Post a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.
- Handle the user data securely, including transmitting it using modern cryptography (for example, over HTTPS)."

So yes, you need a Privacy Policy. What is says is a legal matter for you and your lawyers. But you should read all of what the Policy Center says about User privacy.

Comment: What is the real confusion is, this app doesn't read personally identifiable information! Storage permission is for only download files!

Comment: what they mean by ... Handle the user data securely, including transmitting it using modern cryptography (for example, over HTTPS)."